# Relative path in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to make an Automator action that copies a set of files from a folder to another folder that is one folder up and then two folders down from the original files. In other words: ../Folder1/Folder2. The Automator action would be in the same folder as the files, but the root folder will be duplicated and renamed across multiple computers, so the path MUST be relative.

My understanding is that I need to run an Applescript to grab the current path and then do...something. I have zero scripting experience. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: I know the shell can be intimidating, but while this can be done in Automator, it is so easy in the shell that you might want to start getting comfortable with it: `cp files*.txt ../Folder1/Folder2`

Comment: Forget my dumb question The Action IS an Application :-)

Comment: Have added two more versions to my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of AppleScript, you could do it by adding a **Run Shell Script** module with this content:

```
for F in "$@"; do
    cp "$F" "${F%/*/*}/Folder1/Folder2/${F##*/}"
done
```

Edit the names of Folder1/Folder2 to match your actual case.

Choose **As arguments** from the Pass Input: pop-up at right where it says *to stdin*.

`$@` stores the full path of all files selected. `$F` is each individual file's path as it is processed by the `for` loop. The weird `${F%/*/*}` is the full path of the file *minus* the file name and its parent folder name. The weird `${F##*/}` is the file name itself.

Test first for safety!

[image: Image of script]

The other way to do it, which I think would be easier in the long run:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type `cd`<kbd>space</kbd> and drag the folder containing your files into the window. (This will paste in the path to that folder. Be sure to include the space after `cd` before you drag-and-drop.)
3. Type `cp *Video* ../Folder1/Folder2`
4. Done!

Comment: So, your other answer: cp files*.txt ../Folder1/Folder2 is simpler and better?  This answer with the for-loop is more general, in that it doesn't assume the particular extension of ".txt"?

Comment: Well, the command that you type each time you need it is the most flexible, moreso than the for-loop. I just put `*.txt` as an example of a way to select multiple files. That could be anything. If you go the Automator route, then you have the step of using the GUI to select files (may be easier or harder depending on the context), but it is definitely harder to change the `Folder1/Folder2` destination by editing the Automator script each time you want to use it.

Comment: I am staring at your shell script, and I really have no idea what to do with it. Hand holding would be greatly appreciated: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/155264288/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-11%20at%209.05.09%20AM.png

Comment: I edited the answer. I had neglected to mention that the `as arguments` option needed to be selected. Also added the native shell command, if you want to get adventurous.

Comment: I got it all working with multiple instances of each step to copy different sets of images. Thanks so much for your help! I'd upvote you if I had the karma :-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE* trimmed down the code a little bit, and corrected the path

Since you asked for applescript…

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set thefolderPath to "folder1:folder2:"
        set mycontainer to (path to me)
            set movePath to folder thefolderPath of container of (path to me)'s container as alias
        duplicate input to movePath

    end tell

end run
```

This also does away with the copy action since the duplication is done here also.

---

UPDATE 2

With this version. It does not matter where the App is. The path is worked out by where the files are.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set thefolderPath to "folder1:folder2:"
    tell application "Finder"
        set thisItem to item 1 of input as alias
         set movePath to folder thefolderPath of container of (thisItem)'s container as alias
        duplicate input to movePath

    end tell

end run
```

---

UPDATE 3

This version is the same as update 2. But will test for your folder1 and folder2.

If either folder does not exist it will make them and move the files to them.
If only folder2 does not exist. Then it will only make that folder inside folder1. Meaning existing items in folder1 are safe.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set thefolderPath to "folder1/folder2/"
    tell application "Finder"
        set thisItem to item 1 of input as alias
        set movePath to container of (thisItem)'s container as alias
        set theTestPath to ((POSIX path of movePath) & "/" & thefolderPath)

        if (do shell script "/bin/test -e " & quoted form of theTestPath & " ; echo $?") is "1" then
            -- 1 is false
            do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of theTestPath

        end if
        set theActualPath to (POSIX file theTestPath) as alias
        duplicate input to theActualPath

    end tell

end run
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! Unfortunately, it only works when I run it from Automator, so the files get deposited within the Applications folder (after I set up the proper folder structure within Applications).
When I try and run it from the Finder (even when it's within the Applications folder), I get a dialog box telling me there was an Applescript error.

Comment: Here is a video demonstrating: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/155264288/2013-09-11%2008.46.12.mov

Comment: AH I have updated it. I did not relies you had the app in 'Folder'

Comment: By the way how is this used and why. Just thought it is an odd way to hard code an app to copy some files.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks so much for working on this. Beroe's answer above worked for me, but I'm going to study your answer as I imagine it could be helpful in other situations. The way I'm using this is to take a whole bunch of images, each of which have one or more "tags" in their file names, and triage them to different folders based on their tags. The whole thing needs to be portable because it will end up getting duplicated, renamed, and moved to many different computers.